# RStudio Shiny searchable selectInput with Ctrl+F browser when selectize=FALSE

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I have a `selectInput` box in my RStudio Shiny website, and I have it set up with `selectize=FALSE` because it's a long list, so I specify the height and width that I desire. I would like to know if there is any way to enable searching for text inside the choices of the `selectInput` box using the Find utility in my browser (Ctrl+F).

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible. At least I do not know how to do it without selectize.

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically change a box from selectize FALSE to TRUE?

Comment: Sorry but no, you have to make this decision when you create the select(ize) input.

Comment: Is it possible to do a selectize=TRUE and then limit the height of the ids shown in the box to a certain number of pixels?

Comment: Perhaps CSS works. I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to @Yihui 's comment, I use the following:

```
selectInput(inputId = "vizvars1", label = "X-variable", choices = vars,
  multiple = input$viz_multiple == 'multiple', 
  selectize = input$viz_multiple == 'single')
```

In your case you might set selectize based on the number of entries in another input (e.g., length(input$mylistofoptions) )

Comment: I am having a formatting issue when I switch from `multiple` to `single`. Any ideas how to solve it? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998396/rstudio-shiny-dynamic-selectize