# RStudio Shiny dynamic selectize

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

In my RStudio Shiny, I got my `selectInput` inside my `server.R`, and on `ui.R` I got a `tags` statement to change the width and height of the select box.

It works when the page is loaded, but it reverts to the default size when I got to the single type. Any ideas how to solve it?

On ui.R

```
# [...]
  ,div(class="span6"
   ,radioButtons("viz_multiple", "Select Type:",
          c("Select From List (can use Up/Down + Enter)" = "multiple",
            "Search One (Delete then type keyword)"  = "single")
    )
   )
  )
  ,div(class='row-fluid'
  ,div(class='span12', uiOutput("image_list"))
  ,tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", "select#iimage_list             { width: 1000px; height: 40px; }"))
  )
 # [...]
```

On server.R

```
# [...]

output$image_list <- renderUI({
  imagelist = image_ls()
  iimage_list <- as.vector(sort(unique(as.character(imagelist)),decreasing=TRUE))
  length_list = length(iimage_list)
  selectInput("iimage_list",paste0("samples (",length_list,")"),choices=iimage_list, selectize = input$viz_multiple == 'single')
})
# [...]
```

Any ideas how to apply the `tags` command also when the user switches from `multiple` to `single`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the css dynamically also. To target the selectize input you need to target `select#dataset + .selectize-control` rather then `select#dataset`

library(shiny)

```
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    radioButtons("viz_multiple", "Select Type:",
                 c("Select From List (can use Up/Down + Enter)" = "multiple",
                   "Search One (Delete then type keyword)"  = "single")
    )
    , uiOutput("myUI")
  ),
  server = function(input, output){
    output$myUI <- renderUI({
      myCSS <-if(input$viz_multiple == 'single'){
        tags$style(type="text/css", "select#dataset + .selectize-control{ width: 1000px; height: 40px; }")
      }else{
        tags$style(type="text/css", "select#dataset { width: 1000px; height: 40px; }")
      }
      tagList(
        selectInput('dataset', 'Choose Dataset', c('mtcars', 'iris'), selectize = (input$viz_multiple == 'single'))
        , myCSS
      )
    })
  }
))
```

or have two seperate CSS entries one for the `select` and one for the `selectize`:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    radioButtons("viz_multiple", "Select Type:",
                 c("Select From List (can use Up/Down + Enter)" = "multiple",
                   "Search One (Delete then type keyword)"  = "single")
    )
    , uiOutput("myUI")
    , tags$style(type="text/css", "select#dataset + .selectize-control{ width: 1000px; height: 40px; }")
    , tags$style(type="text/css", "select#dataset { width: 1000px; height: 40px; }")
  ),
  server = function(input, output){
    output$myUI <- renderUI({
      selectInput('dataset', 'Choose Dataset', c('mtcars', 'iris'), selectize = (input$viz_multiple == 'single'))
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: I copy+pasted this new version, but it does not behave differently to the original one. If I remove the corresponding `tags` statement in `ui.R`, and just use the new version in your answer, also same behavior...

Comment: You will need to provide reproducible code otherwise it is hard to comment further.

Comment: The fact that it does resize it to the right size when loading the page with the version in your answer, makes me think it is applying the tagList correctly. But when I change the `input$viz_multiple` option in the loaded page, it goes back to default size...